# Developer tools can not be pinned/docked any more

Tags: internet-explorer-11, developer-tools

I'm running Internet Explorer 11.0.9600.18978 on Windows 8.
At some point I opened the developer tools using F12 and undocked/unpinned the tools, so that it became a separte window.

When I now try to dock/pin it again, the pin button is clickable but does not do anything. The shortcut `Ctrl + P` also does not work. Drag and Drop also does not work: The window does not snap-in/dock

[image]

I already read [Navigating the F12 Developer Tools Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh968260(v=vs.85).aspx) and also followed the steps described in the support article [The menu bar and the toolbar are missing in Internet Explorer on Windows Vista or Windows XP or in Windows Explorer on Windows XP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/962963/the-menu-bar-and-the-toolbar-are-missing-in-internet-explorer-on-windo) (yes, I have seen that is not for Windows 8 but I nevertheless gave it a try).

Any ideas how to dock/pin the tools again?

Comment: Have you tried drag and drop (to the appropriate location) on your undocked window?

Comment: Yes, but I does not snap in/dock at the main window.

Comment: Cannot repro. The pin button for me docks it again (on Windows 7)

Comment: This issue happens for me as well.

Comment: Cannot reproduce - button & shortcut work (only on the second try), Windows 10, IE version 11.175.18362.0. Have you tried to reset IE? Maybe a corrupted user profile?

Comment: @harrymc I don't have any access to this machine any more and therefor can not try to reset the profile :(

Comment: @sashoalm: You have posted a bounty on a post where the poster cannot answer questions about that computer. Can you answer them yourself?

Comment: @harrymc probably won't need to, I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/31540883/492336 and I did set my TabProcGrowth to 0 at one time to force it to use 64-bit IE11 for the tabs.

Comment: @sashoalm: If you have a working solution, please post here an answer. Unfortunately, you cannot award the bounty to yourself.

Comment: @harrymc Just confirmed - the TabProcGrowth was the problem. If you are interested in reproducing it, just set TabProcGrowth to 0 and you'll reproduce the issue (see my answer below). As for the points, don't sweat it, it's just points :)

Answer (score 0):

Just confirmed, the issue was that TabProcGrowth=0 had been set for me (I was trying to force IE11 to use 64-bit processes for the tabs).

The solution outlined in https://stackoverflow.com/a/31540883/492336 works:

> Change the tabprocgrowth to be 1 :
>
> ```
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main]
> "TabProcGrowth"="1"
> ```